# how to prevent image pixelation when resizing page or moving div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem where when the page is resized or a div with an image in it moves on the page, the image gets pixelated, then becomes sharp again a few seconds after the page stops moving. 
In my CSS code, the img tag has a "-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" property, but even without that the same behavior occurs. Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: Please show  me your codes or create a fiddle @ fiddle.com

Comment: What browser are you looking at? I suspect that CSS will only apply to IE.